# Not showing string showing this weird error? function(){return Fn("DataSnapshot.val",0,0,arguments.length),this.node_.val()}

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

When I try to pull the data this is what happens, I am using child_added to be real-time.
I feel like I have to convert it to a string/but I do not know how
Sorry for my english
here is the js file

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var config = {
            apiKey: "AIzaSyB9p1VvVfhnbrcDwUKUuSqw9aQsqnDi4nQ",
            authDomain: "html5project-870df.firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "https://html5project-870df.firebaseio.com",
            projectId: "html5project-870df",
            storageBucket: "html5project-870df.appspot.com",
            messagingSenderId: "54935462861"
          };
    //firebase.initializeApp(config);
    if (!firebase.apps.length) {
        firebase.initializeApp({});
    }
    var database = firebase.database();
    var Rootref = database.ref().child("users");

    Rootref.on("child_added", snap => { 
    var test = "test5765";  

    var name = snap.child("user").val;
    console.log(name);
    $("#read").append("<tr><td>"+name+"</td></tr>");
```

Here is the result

```
function(){return Fn("DataSnapshot.val",0,0,arguments.length),this.node_.val()}
function(){return Fn("DataSnapshot.val",0,0,arguments.length),this.node_.val()}
function(){return Fn("DataSnapshot.val",0,0,arguments.length),this.node_.val()}
```

It posts three times because there are three events
Any help is appreciated
Here is the github link
https://github.com/SaiVeer04/transcriber/blob/master/read.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot) `snapshot.child(<>).val()` is a method not a property.

```
var name = snap.child("user").val(); // try val() instead of val
console.log(name);
$("#read").append("<tr><td>"+name+"</td></tr>");
```

Comment: Thank you,but what should I do

Comment: @SaiVeeramachaneni did you try to replace the part of code I suggested? Look again please.